# Bash extract project name from url github

Tags: regex, bash, substring

I have the following code:

```sh
url='https://github.com/Project/name-app.git'
echo $url
```

I have to get this back to me, i.e. the name of the project regardless of the owner of the project.

Result:

`name-app`

Comment: This is a poor duplicate.  While it can be used to answer the question, it does not entirely do so.  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use string manipulation in Bash:

```sh
url='https://github.com/Project/name-app.git'
url="${url##*/}" # Remove all up to and including last /
url="${url%.*}"  # Remove up to the . (including) from the right
echo "$url"
# => name-app
```

See the [online Bash demo](https://ideone.com/pmmg8d).

Another approach with `awk`:

```sh
url='https://github.com/Project/name-app.git'
url=$(awk -F/ '{sub(/\..*/,"",$NF); print $NF}' <<< "$url")
echo "$url"
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/hbGHCJ). Here, the field delimiter is set to `/`, the last field value is taken and all after first `.` is removed from it (together with the `.`), and that result is returned.

Comment: I can ask you something that is always about this, so as not to have to reopen a new problem.

Comment: Yes. Ask here to keep everything related to the current problem in one thread.

Comment: I have the following code, I would like to get the result printed below.
https://pastebin.com/syP0xzug

The problem is if the mold without assigning it works correctly, if I assign it to a variable it does not work well.
Also the part where it says code and endCode, I wish it could be solved with a single instruction with assignment to a variable, do you think it is feasible?

Comment: @Paul Is the `git@github.com-nameUser expo/react-native-read-more-text.git` output the expected output?

Comment: Result: `git@github.com-nameUser:expo/react-native-read-more-text.git`
Find the comment at the end with the expected result.

Comment: @Paul See [this Bash demo](https://ideone.com/XT95O0). Initialize the two variables with `IFS=: read -r email url <<< "$url"` and then all you need is to combine the result from the three variables, `p="$email-$user:$url"`.

Comment: @Paul A `sed` solution is also possible, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/vpLLYj).

Comment: Thx, but last example the one with sed, doesn't seem to work.
I did a test on: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php

Comment: @Paul It is really weird, the first time I see this. For some unknown reason, `&` is not recognized as the backreference to the whole match in `sed` replacement (RHS, right-hand side). So, work around it using a capturing group, `p=$(echo "$url" | sed "s|\([^:]*\)|\1-$user|")`

Comment: Thx, it seems to work, I don't understand why the one before didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use grep regexp:

```
url='https://github.com/Project/name-app.git'
echo $url | grep -oP ".*/\K[^\.]*"
```

You can use bash expansion:

```
url='https://github.com/Project/name-app.git'
mytemp=${url##*/}
echo ${mytemp%.*}
```

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```
echo $url | awk -F'\\.|/' '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

***OR*** to make sure last value is always ending with `.git` try a bit tweak in above code:

```
echo "$url" | awk -F'\\.|/' '$NF=="git"{print $(NF-1)}'
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `sed` try following:

```
echo "$url" | sed 's/.*\///;s/\..*//'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# my prefered solution
url='https://github.com/Project/name-app.git' 
basename $url .git
> name-app

# others
sed 's/\(.*\/\)\([^\/]*\)\.\(\w*\)$/\2/g'  <<<$url
1.https://github.com/Project/ 
2.name-app 
#
awk -F"[/.]" '{print $(NF-1)}' <<<$url
awk -F"[/.]" '{print $6}' <<<$url
tr '/.' '\n' <<<$url|tail -2|grep -v git
```